# И снова xDebug+netbeans, прошу помочь подружить их между собой

Tags: unix, ssh, netbeans, xdebug

День добрый всем!
Прошу помочь решить уже классический квест с xDebug :)

**Итак, имеем:**

Удаленный сервер (shared hosting от nic.ru), FreeBSD/Apache+Nginx/PHP-5.6, 
xdebug 4.2.1 успешно собран и установлен, phpinfo() это подтверждает.
Настройки xDebug в php.ini:

```
zend_extension="/home/nosorog/usr/php/lib/xdebug.so"
xdebug.remote_enable=1
xdebug.remote_autostart=1
xdebug.remote_host=localhost
xdebug.remote_port=9009
;xdebug.remote_connect_back=1
xdebug.remote_handler=dbgp
xdebug.remote_mode=req
xdebug.idekey="netbeans-xdebug"
xdebug.remote_log="/home/nosorog/logs/xdebug/xdebug.log"
xdebug.profiler_output_dir="/home/nosorog/logs/xdebug/profiler/"
xdebug.trace_output_dir="/home/nosorog/logs/xdebug/trace/"
```

В общем, xDebug запускается, логи пишутся, попытка установки соединения при обновлении страницы сайта тоже имеет место (об этом ниже).

Порт нестандартный (т.к. читал мнение, что 9000 иногда занимается какими-то расширениями апача), но везде прописан корректно, это проверял первым делом. Другие номера портов также пробовал, на всякий случай.

Локально: WinXP, NetBeans 8.1,
пробрасываем обратный ssh-туннель с помощью Putty:

```
R9009 - localhost:9009
```

проверяем на той стороне с помощью netstat -a|grep 9009 :

```
tcp6       0      0 localhost.9009         *.*                    LISTEN
```

туннель есть, порт слушается.

**Проблема:**

При попытке запустить отладочную сессию (учитывая, что autostart=1, для этого просто обновляем страницу сайта) - на той стороне есть попытка соединения,

```
tcp4       0      0 nosorog.nichost..14107 localhost.9009         SYN_SENT
tcp6       0      0 localhost.9009         *.*                    LISTEN
```

но здесь нетбинс никак не реагерует. На сервере в логах xDebuga -

```
E: Time-out connecting to client. :-(
```

через пару секунд на сервере соединение переходит в тайм-вейт

```
tcp4       0      0 nosorog.nichost..14107 localhost.9009         TIME_WAIT
tcp6       0      0 localhost.9009         *.*                    LISTEN
```

, а через какое-то время соединение исчезает совсем, остается только листен:

```
tcp6       0      0 localhost.9009         *.*                    LISTEN
```

**А теперь - странности:**

- если с той стороны попробовать `ssh -p 9009 localhost` или или `nc localhost 9009` или `telnet localhost 9009` - то соединение удается установить: **НА СЕРВЕРЕ** - **netstat** показывает localhost:9009  ESTABLISHED; **НА ЛОКАЛЬНОЙ МАШИНЕ** - **тестовый листенер** принимает коннект; **нетбинс** - либо игнорит (если оттуда `ssh`или `telnet`либо падает (если оттуда `nc`т.е. в принципе - *реагирует*; а **wireshark** - во всех случаях (все шесть возможных комбинаций) - *видит трафик*. другими словами - тунель в принципе работоспособен;
- а если с той стороны пытается соединиться **xDebug** или **тестовый скрипт** (суть которого сводится к `sock.connect(('localhost', 9009))`, скрипт локально проверен) - коннект НЕ случается (**НА СЕРВЕРЕ** - `SYN_SENT` на порту и отвал по таймауту, **ЛОКАЛЬНО** - полная тишина как в **нетстате** так и в **wireshark**).

**Собственно, вопрос:**

как быть? куда еще копать? что я мог упустить? в чем принципиальная разница этих 2х вариантов (почему одни могут, а другие нет)?

мои знания никсов и сетевой науки на этом закончились, поэтому и обращаюсь :)

заранее спасибо за любые подсказки.

Comment: А у NetBeans правильный порт/ide key задан в настройках? Ну и может у вас есть какие-то проблемы с брандмауэром и прослушиванием портов приложениями?

Comment: порт/ide-key - да, те же что и в php.ini (9009, netbeans-xdebug)

Comment: firewall отключал полностью на время тестов, как штатный так и comodo... 
но тут какое дело - если даже на локальной машине включить comodo и запустить тестовый листенер - ssh и telnet с удаленного сервера успешно коннектятся, а xdebug - нет... т.е. на локальной машине ничего не поменял, только другим инструментом на сервере воспользовался - ситуация поменялась... поэтому мне кажется, что firewall тут не мешает даже во включенном состоянии...

но естественно, на всякий случай, я его отрубаю полностью когда пытаюсь что-то еще протестить...